# HTACCESS - Url www.somedomain.com/#sth to www.somedomain.com/sth

Tags: .htaccess

Hi i want when the user clicks a link with href="www.somedomain.com/#sth" the browser redirected to window with www.somedomain.com/#sth and stays in the same page of course, but the url becomes www.somedomain.com/sth in address bar, but is understood as www.somedomain.com/#sth so no problems arise.

Comment: Well, I am not too skilled in this area, but you might want to clean up your question, and make it more clear, because I cannot follow your thought pattern ^^

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly at all, you wouldn't use .htaccess files to do this. You'll need to call an AJAX function on hash change.